# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods, all functions are properly enclosed

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

```
namespace Randomizer {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code. I tried to compile it in cmd, and that's the error it spat out. Anyone can explain whatever is going on here?

Side note, I created this file in VSCode, and it has no csproj file; it's simply a .cs file, nothing more. Maybe that could be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with that code is that you're missing a `using` statement.  This

```
using System;

namespace Randomizer {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles and runs through the .NET Framework compiler:

```
C:\test>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc foo.cs

C:\test>foo.exe
hello world
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what I did wrong...
I did put one in, but my python infested brain got me to type down "import" instead of using. Thanks for the help!